# ngTable don't updated after add new data

Tags: angularjs, json, ngtable

my problem is if I add new item to the database the ngTable don't updated with new data automatically but if I refresh the page (f5) the data is shown.
I use ng table to show data.

PS: the AngularJS consume data from JSON produced by restful WS from a JEE backend connected to a dataBase.

the ng-table :

```
<table ng-table="tablePy" show-filter="true"
                   class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th> Code </th>
                    <th> Libellé</th>
                    <th>Code Alphabetique 2</th>
                    <th>Code Alphabetique 3</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr data-ng-repeat=" py in paysValues  | filter:searchValeur ">

                    <td align="right"> {{py.codPay}}</td>
                    <td > {{py.libPay}}</td>
                    <td> {{py.codAlph2}}</td>
                    <td> {{py.codAlph3}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

the function that fill the table is :

```
var initPaysData = function () {
    var promise =
        allPaysService.getPays();
    promise.then(
        function (res) {
            $scope.paysValues = res.data;
            $scope.tablePy = new NgTableParams({}, {dataset: $scope.paysValues});
        },
        function (error) {
            $log.error('failure Pays charging', error);
        })
};
initPaysData();
```

I use the factory to get All data from the WS:

```
BrokoApp.factory('allPaysService', function ($http) {
return {
    getPays: function () {
        return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/BrokWeb/webresources/referentiel/pays');
    }
}
});
```

this code work but if I add new item to the table is don't shown 
the code of add is:

```
$scope.addPays = function () {
    $scope.selectedPy = $scope.libPay;
    ngDialog.openConfirm({
        template: 'modalDialogAdd',
        className: 'ngdialog-theme-default',
        scope: $scope
    }).then(function () {
        console.log('***** before add length=' + $scope.paysValues.length);
        ajouterPays();
        initPaysData();
        console.log('***** after add length=' + $scope.paysValues.length);
        $scope.tablePy.total($scope.paysValues.length);
        $scope.tablePy.reload();
    }, function () {
        setNotification(notifications, 'danger', 'Erreur', 'Vous avez annule l operation');
    });
};
```

the console.log show that the length of the List of data is the same before and after Add, the console show:

```
***** before add length=152
***** after add length=152
 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/BrokWeb/webresources/referentiel/pays".
a XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost:8080/BrokWeb/webresources/referentiel/pays".
```

the function AjouterPays is

```
var ajouterPays = function () {

    var paysData = {
        codAlph2: $scope.codAlph2,
        // getting data from the adding form
    };
    var res = addPaysService.addPys(paysData);
    res.success(function () {
        setNotification(notifications, 'success', 'Succes', 'Ajout de ' + paysData.libPay);
    });
    res.error(function () {
        setNotification(notifications, 'danger', 'Erreur', 'Erreur est servenue au cours de la creation');
    });
    // Making the fields empty
    $scope.codAlph2 = '';
};
```

i use the factory addPaysService to post data

```
BrokoApp.factory('addPaysService', function ($http) {
return {
    addPys: function (PyData) {
        return $http.post('http://localhost:8080/BrokWeb/webresources/referentiel/pays', PyData);
    }
}
});
```

Can anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple approach for the updation of the data after you post/save any data or record to the database can be

just have a get request after the save/update is successful

i mean you can call the service/factory function which has the get request to the data base  and then assign the response to the scope object of the table

Thank you

Comment: thank you. I should call the factory of getting allData in the success part of the post. 
 res.success(function () {
         initPaysData()
        setNotification(notifications, 'success', 'Succes', 'Ajout de ' + paysData.libPay);
    });

Answer (score 1):

In case of the POST success, you can add the created element (if returned by your service) in $scope.paysValues.
Maybe something like that :

```
var ajouterPays = function () {

    var paysData = {
        codAlph2: $scope.codAlph2,
        // getting data from the adding form
    };
    var promise = addPaysService.addPys(paysData);
    promise.success(function ( response ) {

        $scope.paysValues.push( response.data );

        setNotification(notifications, 'success', 'Succes', 'Ajout de ' + paysData.libPay);
    });
    promise.error(function () {
        setNotification(notifications, 'danger', 'Erreur', 'Erreur est servenue au cours de la creation');
    });
    // Making the fields empty
    $scope.codAlph2 = '';
};
```

If your service does not return the created element in case of success, you can simple push the data you sent instead.

PS: note that success() and error() methods on an HttpPromise are deprecated from Angular 1.4.4 (see https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/docs/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: in ajouterPays  function part, you might have to add the new data coming from the server as a parameter, sth like: res.success(function (newPaysData) { $scope.paysValues.push( newPaysData );})

Comment: Yep, you're 100% right - of course in case the service returns some data after post :-)